# Bitmap.copy failing where createScaledBitmap works

Tags: android, bitmap, crash, copy

I'm having a problem with the Bitmap.copy function.  This code works okay,

```
Bitmap tempBM = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sourceBitmap, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), false);

//Ensure that the bitmap is mutable and not copied from the original in the case where no scaling is required
m_bwBitmap = tempBM.copy(tempBM.getConfig(), true);
if (tempBM!=sourceBitmap)
{
    tempBM.recycle();
}
```

But this doesn't...

```
m_bwBitmap = sourceBitmap.copy(sourceBitmap.getConfig(), true);
```

sourceBitmap starts as immutable and I want m_bwBitmap to be mutable.

It doesn't crash as such but it does break the debugger as if something has gone wrong in the android function somewhere.  The application then crashes later on. If I replace it with the top code, everything works fine.

However, I have now started getting crash reports from JellyBean, throwing a null pointer exception on the line with the tempBM.copy on it.  So, I have to sort this out but currently the top code is the only source that will work at all.  I'm testing it on an Android 4.0 device.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post a stack trace from one of your crash reports? That might help us to identify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I have answered this (well at least halfway anyway).

It is something to do with the Bitmap.Config.  If I change the line to

```
m_bwBitmap = sourceBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

then it works fine.

Note, the original source bitmap comes from a line like this...

```
Bitmap sourceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pictureFile);
```

pictureFile is a GIF.

However, I don't really know why decodeFile is producing something with a seemingly invalid Config.  If I check the config of sourceBitmap, it returns null ?!?